# Using JSP (or Velocity templates) aside to Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, jsp, spring-mvc, velocity

I have a Spring Boot web application, that uses JSP (and Velocity templates is another app) as its renderer. I am considerring migrating the render technique to Angular JS.

In my apps, I currently have some RequestMapping methods in the controllers, each populates the ModelMap and returns JSP or Velocity templates.

Spring Controller Exmaple:

```
@RequestMapping("/somePage") 
public String somePage(ModelMap model) {
    model.addAttribute("SomeObject", getSomeObject());
    return "tmpl_some_page.vm"
}
```

Then I use my ModelMap attributes to render the view.
My Velocity Template "tmpl_some_page.vm":

```
    <body>
          $someObject
    </body>
```

As said above, I want to migrate to Angular JS. As I understood by now (very new at Angular), Angular works in the opposite direction: the Spring controller does not populate the ModelMap, but the Angular frontend controller.

My question is that: is it possible to combine both JSP/Velocity and Angular JS? Is it possible to populate the ModelMap in Spring controller, passing it to the Angular model and use it as json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking whether angular will render a velocity template the answer is no....since a velocity template engine is required to render the velocity template....However is your case if you just want convert your velocity template to angular template then you would have to return json data directly to the controller....instead of putting it in the model map since you would not be able to access request scope in a javascript file....so directly return json in the response body and pass the required json object to angular js template.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, let me just understand this. Currently, the order of request proccess is this: hit url -> invoke method in controller -> render velocity template. In angular, when you hit url - it first renders the html and only than approaches the controller?

Comment: In angular when you navigate using a router.....it loads the template first and then invokes the controller performing digest operations to bind data into the template....that is why if you debug the loading you will see {} these tags..indicating that all the data has not been bound...if you are not using ui-router then you can create a directive binding a controller to that and placing it in the ui....once the directive is called from the ui the controller will immediately be called and it will load all the data the directive needs to execute.